# An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to recomplete the Hartl rails tutorial, but when I run bundle install after changing my Gemfile to the one that he provides i get this message:

```
An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried installing rack on its own and it worked, but then when I run bundle install I get this same message. I tried running a different rails app with the default gem file and everything worked, but this does not. It also will not allow my to run Rails sever because of it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to restart my terminal window... geez